# Strange MERGE behaviour when using static/constant ON clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g, merge-statement

```
CREATE TABLE test (c1 NUMBER(10) NOT NULL);

exec DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG ( 'test', 'err_test');
```

I want to insert into table `test` some values from an other table, and log the errors. I also want to log the ids of records which could not be inserted into the err_test table. In pseudocode this would result in something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test(c1)
SELECT some_nr AS special_nr FROM some_table_which_has_an_unique_id_for_each_number
LOG ERRORS INTO err_test('Could not insert record with id:' || some_table.id /* where id is the id number of the special_nr */ ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

The above obviously doesn't work because `src.id` is unknown. But I can do the above insert with a merge statement that *acts* as an insert statement:

```
MERGE INTO test trg
USING (SELECT NULL AS special_nr, 17 AS id FROM DUAL ) src
ON      (1 = 2) -- force INSERTS (!!) Not using INSERT statement because in err log extra data is needed.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT  (trg.c1)
        VALUES  (src.special_nr)
LOG ERRORS INTO err_test('Could not insert record with id:' || src.id) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

After executing the above, the error is not logged in the err_table, but thrown back to the user:

```
    ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
    ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCV_DPN"."TEST"."C1")
```

String too long? Then I try without the concatenation in the err_mesg$:

```
MERGE INTO test trg
USING (SELECT NULL AS special_nr, 17 AS id FROM DUAL ) src
ON      (1 = 2) -- force INSERTS (!!) Not using INSERT statement because in err log extra data is needed.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT  (trg.c1)
        VALUES  (src.special_nr)
LOG ERRORS INTO err_test(src.id) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Auch:

```
    ORA-38908: internal error occurred during DML Error Logging
    ORA-01024: invalid datatype in OCI call
    ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCV_DPN"."TEST"."C1")
```

It becomes even better:

```
MERGE INTO test trg
USING (SELECT NULL AS special_nr, 17 AS id FROM DUAL ) src
ON      (1 = 2) -- force INSERTS (!!) Not using INSERT statement because in err log extra data is needed.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT  (trg.c1)
        VALUES  (src.special_nr)
LOG ERRORS INTO err_test('Could not insert record with id:' || nvl(src.id, -1)) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Now I am kicked:

```
    ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
    Process ID: 25352
    Session ID: 171 Serial number: 979
```

What's going on here? Seems the `1 = 2` is the culprit, because

```
MERGE INTO test trg
USING (SELECT NULL AS special_nr, 17 AS id FROM DUAL ) src
ON      (src.id IS NULL) -- force INSERTS (!!) Not using INSERT statement because in err log extra data is needed.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT  (trg.c1)
        VALUES  (src.special_nr)
LOG ERRORS INTO err_test('Could not insert record with id:' || src.id) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

works as it should and (!!) logs the error in the `err_table`

```
    ORA_ERR_NUMBER$     ORA_ERR_MESG$                                                   ORA_ERR_ROWID$  ORA_ERR_OPTYP$  ORA_ERR_TAG$                            C1
    1400                ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCV_DPN"."TEST"."C1")                      I               Could not insert record with id:17
```

Now it works without issues.

**Can someone explain to me what is going on here and/or also give a better approach for solving the above problem where extra information from the source table has to be logged in the `ORA_ERR_MESG$` field.**

**Note:** According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_9016.htm) I can use `1 = 2`:
*To insert all of the source rows into the table, you can use a constant filter predicate in the ON clause condition. An example of a constant filter predicate is ON (0=1).*

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've missed one possible culprit: the inclusion of a row value in the tag parameter. I don't believe that this functionality is intended to provide the functionality that you are attempting to use it for. While I can't find any documentation to that effect, a simple change to the initial `merge` (the one with the concatenation error) seems to confirm it:

```
MERGE INTO test trg
USING (SELECT NULL AS special_nr, 17 AS id FROM DUAL ) src
ON      (1 = 2) -- force INSERTS (!!) Not using INSERT statement because in err log extra data is needed.
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT  (trg.c1)
        VALUES  (src.special_nr)
LOG ERRORS INTO err_test('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

This SQL is successful, despite the tag exceeding the length of the concatenated value that was originally provided.

To get the more detailed logging that you desire, I'd suggest using a cursor for loop containing an insert. It may be slightly slower, but it will allow you to log as much detail as you'd like when there's an error.

---

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#BGBEIACB) appears to support this conclusion, though it's more implied than stated outright. In describing the "simple expression" allowed for error logging, it states: "The expression can be either a text literal, a number literal, or a general SQL expression such as a bind variable."

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I deliberately excluded your example because that wasn't what I was after, but it didn't throw the error. Please also consider my note in the original post.

Comment: Imho, the above is a "general SQL expression". Anyhow, using `ON(src.id IS NULL)` seems to work.

Comment: I'd advise against using your current solution. It's perilously close to undocumented behavior, and I wouldn't be at all surprised if a future version broke this code. It's seems clear to me, from the strange errors that resulted from some of the attempts, that this is not the intended usage of the `LOG ERRORS` clause.